# What is this plane, based on its wing?

Tags: aircraft-identification, airbus

Here is the picture of the wing of a plane. Does anyone know which plane it is? The flight number was AF 1834 going from Paris CDG to Berlin Tegel in november 2015. The plane was from Air France and to me it was a A321 but not 100% sure. From what I found A318, A320 and A321 where used by Air France to go to Berlin from this [source](https://www.jetphotos.com/showphotos.php?aircraft=all&airline=all&country-location=location%253BBerlin%2520Tegel%2520-%2520EDDT&photographer-group=all&category=all&keywords-type=airline&keywords-contain=3&keywords=Air%20France&photo-year=2015&width=&height=&genre=all&search-type=Advanced&sort-order=0).

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very likely it was an A321.

On underside of the wing you can read the top of the letters of the registration. First should be F for France, third is clearly a T. The shapes match F-GTA#, where # is either B, D or P.
These are registrations of [Air France A321](https://www.airfleets.net/flottecie/Air%20France.htm) aircraft.

Answer (score 9):

This is an Airbus A321-111/-212 variant.

I can't second the original poster regarding the registration (though likely correct), but the underside of the wing has double-slotted flaps vs that of the single-slotted flaps on the A318/A319/A320.  You can tell based on the additional flap fairings on the trailing edge of the wing. The A321 has five flap fairings beyond the engine whereas the A320 has 3:

[image: A320 and A321 comparison]
(image source: [Airbus Aircraft Characteristics](https://www.airbus.com/en/airport-operations-and-technical-data/aircraft-characteristics))

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE! Nice insight into the Airbus variants. Is there a schematic or drawing available on-line that depicts the different numbers/locations of the flap tracks for the different models?

Comment: @RalphJ You can see the difference in the "scaled drawings" section in the Airbus Aircraft Characteristics documents. I added a picture.

Comment: This is a great answer, I learned something new. This should be the accepted answer. Welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com.